# How To Get Key in a Json File with SimpleJson c#

Tags: c#, json, simplejson

I have a json file in this format:

```
{
  "3874D632": {
    "FirstName": "Jack",
    "LastName": "Andersen"
  },
  "34F43A33": {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith"
  }
```

}

```
StreamReader read_json = new StreamReader(path_json_file);

json = JSONNode.Parse(read_json.ReadToEnd());
read_json.Close();
```

how to obtain 3874D632 or 34F43A33 ??

```
json[????].
```

Comment: Have a look at the Unity3D wiki: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note: this answer refers to the [SimpleJSON library](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) posted on the [UnifyWiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Main_Page) site, which is not to be confused with the completely different [SimpleJson library](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/Serializers/Json/SimpleJson.cs) that ships as part of [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

If the `JSONNode` represents a JSON object, you can cast it to `JSONObject` and from there you can enumerate the key-value pairs like a dictionary.  The `Key` of each key-value pair will have the value you seek.  See example below:

```
string json = @"
{
  ""3874D632"": {
    ""FirstName"": ""Jack"",
    ""LastName"": ""Andersen""
  },
  ""34F43A33"": {
    ""FirstName"": ""John"",
    ""LastName"": ""Smith""
  }
}";

var node = JSONNode.Parse(json);
if (node.Tag == JSONNodeType.Object)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JSONNode> kvp in (JSONObject)node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1} {2}", 
            kvp.Key, kvp.Value["FirstName"].Value, kvp.Value["LastName"].Value));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
3874D632: Jack Andersen
34F43A33: John Smith
```